# How do match list of given probable substring in a txt file with a specific string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a .txt file something like this:

```
pay
pal
```

I want to find out if the list of words in a files is a sub string of a given string (.ie $domain in code below))

Whats the best approach, should I load it up in memory or keep check line one by line on fly?

Note: File can grow in future with potentially more records and each record is in new line

Any code snippet would help me.

Here is what I have so far, but its just outputing once, "SubstringFound! instead of twice "

```
function checklist() 
{
$domain='abpaypal123.com';
$handle = fopen("C:/test_project/black_list.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
print_r($line);
if(strpos($domain, $line) !== false){
    echo "Substring Found!";
}
    }

    fclose($handle);
} 
}
```

Thanks

php

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why did you tag this question with a regular expression, while the code does not contain any?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is outputting `SubstringFound!` only once, as the `$line` contains a newline after pay and strstr will return false for the first line.

You can solve that removing the newline from `$line`

```
function checklist()
{
    $domain='abpaypal123.com';
    $handle = fopen("C:/test_project/black_list.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if(strpos($domain, rtrim($line)) !== false){
                echo "Substring Found!";
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

You might also read the file into memory (if you do not hit a memory limit of course) using for example file_get_contents and then split on `\R` which matches any Unicode newline sequence.

```
function checklist()
{
    $domain='abpaypal123.com';
    $str = file_get_contents("C:/test_project/black_list.txt");
    foreach(preg_split("/\R/", $str) as $line) {
        if(strpos($domain, $line) !== false){
            echo "Substring Found!";
        }
    }
}
```